# How to write Complex SQL but use Predicate (through Dapper)

Tags: c#, sql, dapper, predicate

Am using `Dapper` library with `Sql Server`. Is it possible to use `Predicates` with `Complex Sql Queries` to pass the required parameters in order to filter the Sql Resultset out into a `Single Entity Class`?

```
SELECT * FROM Config.Country 
INNER JOIN Config.State 
ON Config.State.CountryId = Config.Country.CountryId
```

The entity class could have the following structure.

```
public sealed class CountryStateReadDto
{
    //Country table
    public byte CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string ISOCode { get; set; }
    public string DailingCode { get; set; }
    public string WebCode { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    //State table
    public short StateId { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

I know, there is a beautiful [Dapper-Extension](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions) project that does the job, but just for `Single Table only`.

I need to write `Complex Sql Queries` preferably using `Predicates`. Can someone please help me by providing some hints or even solutions would be very helpful too!

If `Predicate` is not an ideal solution then is there anything else I can consider or better than `Predicate`?

> Note: The above Sql example is just a simple query, I have complex
>   queries with > 10 table joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a view

```
Create View StateDetails
SELECT * FROM Config.Country 
INNER JOIN Config.State 
ON Config.State.CountryId = Config.Country.CountryId
```

Once you have your views setup, working with Dapper becomes much easier.

Comment: This make a lot of sense!